# freewheel removal tool for Shimano MF TZ21

Tags: shimano, freewheel

I have a Rockrider 5.1 cycle with a Shimano MFTZ21 freewheel. In order to remove the freewheel, I purchased the [Btwin tool kit](http://www.decathlon.in/cycling/spareparts/maintenance-tools/tool-kit-14-tools/p-244440.htm). But the removal tool provided in the kit does not fit on my freewheel.

Here is a photo of the removal tool in the kit :

[image]

Here is a photo of my freewheel :

[image]

Here you can see that the diameter of the tool is a little too big to go in :

[image]

So now I am considering buying the [Parktool FR-1 freewheel removal tool](http://store.bumsonthesaddle.com/products/park-tool-freewheel-remover-shimano-sachs-aris-sun-race). **But will it fit on my freewheel?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Park FR-1 (or something compatible) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [technical difference](http://sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html) between a cassette and a freewheel. A freewheel contains the ratcheting mechanism while a cassette sits on a freehub which contains the ratcheting mechanism.

It clearly says in that toolkit's page "shimano cassette removal tool". The MF-TZ21 is a freewheel. So Park Tool FR-1 is the right tool. They also have excellent instructions on changing your freewheel [here](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal).

Comment: Thanks. i was aware of this difference, but i took a calculated guess that the cassette removal tool would fit my freewheel before i purchased the toolkit. It has 12 splines and a 22.6 mm diameter, which matches the FR-1 and my freewheel as well. But i think it is a half a mm bigger than my freewheel. That's why i have a strong suspicion that the FR-1 will also have the same problem.

Comment: A Shimano Cassette tool (Park tool FR-5) should have diameter around 23.4 mm while a freewheel tool 23mm. The splines on the freewheel tool (Park tool FR-1.2) are also significantly longer.